# what should I say? why don't you come back?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

I want to know the most natural expression. please help me. 
Context is : If my son went out and he didn't come back home yet. He had told me he will be home by 10. Now it's 12. I've started to worry him. I want to know why he didn't come back. It may be because he forgot time. I'm gonna text him to ask 'why'.

In this situation, should I say "why don't you come back?"
I think it sound weird...

Comment: I recommend that you say either 'why haven't you already come back home?' or 'why haven't you come back home yet?'.

Comment: Even simpler: "Where are you?"

Answer (score 1):

You can say something like 'Why aren't you home yet?'